# Code Ignighter - 404 showing, but correct response

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

i'm working on a website at work and recenctly move it via svn to my localserver so i can work from home...

The setup went okay, no majors... but code ignighter sends 404 Not Found on pages along with the correct response...

For example i can load 'localhost/home' and it fires my controller and i get correct view, but CI also send 404 in headers for the page....!!
this also happens on my js files...

I can force it to send "200 OK", but doing this on every page seams silly..

Has anyone come accross this problem before...?

I'm using;
Code Ignighter: 2.1.0

Apache : 2.0.63

PHP: 5.1.6

this is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|js)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Stackoverflow cropped out the IfModule mod_rewrite.c from my htaccess but i do have them there really

Comment: Are you using the wiredesignz HMVC extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the .htaccess example [from the documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html) a try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

The following line could be responsible for your 404 response:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Comment: if i use that as is, i get error 500 on everything....?! but when i put it in a "if module" etc.. it shows shame as before...??

Comment: Error 500 is an internal server error, are you have mod_rewrite set up on your local machine? Try a phpinfo().